# Oracle Sub Query Error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select SELLS.BEER, SELLS.PRICE, SELLS.BAR 
from   FREQUENTS 
where  FREQUENTS.DRINKER = 'Sally' 
  and  FREQUENTS.BAR IN (select SELLS.BAR from SELLS where PRICE > 5);
```

Here is the error message:

```
ORA-00904: "SELLS"."BAR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 43 Column: 33
```

I have checked all the columns in the table and they look right for me however I couldn't find.

Can someone tell me where is the error? I am trying to solve it without using a JOIN.

Comment: It seems that table SELLS has no column called "BAR".  It may have one called "bar" or "Bar" perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
select s.BEER, s.PRICE, s.BAR 
from FREQUENTS, SELLS s
where FREQUENTS.DRINKER = 'Sally' AND FREQUENTS.BAR IN (select SELLS.BAR from SELLS where PRICE > 5);
```

If I got your logic, try this:

```
select s.BEER, s.PRICE, s.BAR 
from FREQUENTS, SELLS s
where FREQUENTS.DRINKER = 'Sally' AND FREQUENTS.BAR IN (select SELLS.BAR from SELLS where s.PRICE > 5);
```

Comment: There were no errors however the results look incorrect. It displays slows with Price < 5 and Price = 5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

SELLS wasn't JOINED to the main query so what you were selecting wasn't valid.

```
SELECT s.BEER, s.PRICE, s.BAR 
FROM FREQUENTS f
INNER JOIN SELLS s ON f.BAR = s.BAR
WHERE f.DRINKER = 'Sally' 
AND f.BAR IN (SELECT sa.BAR 
              FROM SELLS sa 
              WHERE sa.PRICE > 5);
```

Even simpler possibly:

```
SELECT s.BEER, s.PRICE, s.BAR 
FROM FREQUENTS f
INNER JOIN SELLS s ON f.BAR = s.BAR
WHERE f.DRINKER = 'Sally' 
AND s.PRICE > 5;
```

Without Joins:

```
SELECT s.BEER, s.PRICE, s.BAR 
FROM SELLS s
WHERE s.BAR = (SELECT f.BAR
               FROM FREQUENTS f
               WHERE f.DRINKER = 'Sally')
AND s.PRICE > 5;
```

Comment: Hi! I cannot use a JOIN. I am trying to solve it using a subquery

Comment: Why can't you use a join?